# How would you dynamically create class instances in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm not sure if I am using wrong vocabulary to search for this but I'm not able to find anything that seems to relate to what i'm trying to do.

I have a class that I have made for entering expenses. I has  Name, amount, and dueDate member variables. I am using command line tool to create this class and test it out. What my question is is how would i go about creating an object from my class as the user needs to add an expense. This is what I have done to make it work. I don't like it.

My while loop creates a new instance of my class then gets the user input, sets the member variables of the expense class, and lastly adds the object to an array for latter use.

Everything works i just don't like that every object basically has the same name. I would have liked to create the name of the object from the name the user entered but having users enter names of classes is not good i have found out. So any suggestions please. And I am fairly new to programming so the code is probably very ruff.

```
    NSMutableArray *myExpenses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while (enterMore == 1) 
    {
        Expense *anExpense = [[Expense alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"Enter an expense:\n\nName: ");
        scanf("%s", expenseName);
        billName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: expenseName];
        anExpense.name = billName;

        NSLog(@"\nEnter the amount of the expense: ");
        scanf("%lf", &expenseAmount);
        anExpense.amount = expenseAmount;

        NSLog(@"\nEnter the day of the month the expense is due: ");
        scanf("%d", &dateDue);
        anExpense.dayOfMonthDue = dateDue;

        [myExpenses addObject:anExpense];

        NSLog(@"Enter 1 to enter more expenses anything else to quite: ");
        scanf("%d", &enterMore);

    }
for (int i = 0; i < [myExpenses count]; i++) 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[myExpenses objectAtIndex:i] name]);
    NSLog(@"%f", [[myExpenses objectAtIndex:i] amount]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [[myExpenses objectAtIndex:i] dayOfMonthDue]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every object basically has the same name"? Do you mean "Expense"? "Expense" is the type of the object, not its name.

Comment: name of an object? do you mean the name of the variable that holds a pointer to your object in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was stated in another answer (so I upvoted that one), but maybe an example would help.

```
NSMutableDictionary *myExpenses = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

while (enterMore == 1) 
{
    Expense *anExpense = [[Expense alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Enter an expense:\n\nName: ");
    scanf("%s", expenseName);
    billName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: expenseName];
    anExpense.name = billName;

    NSLog(@"\nEnter the amount of the expense: ");
    scanf("%lf", &expenseAmount);
    anExpense.amount = expenseAmount;

    NSLog(@"\nEnter the day of the month the expense is due: ");
    scanf("%d", &dateDue);
    anExpense.dayOfMonthDue = dateDue;

    [myExpenses setObject:anExpense forKey:billName];

    NSLog(@"Enter 1 to enter more expenses anything else to quite: ");
    scanf("%d", &enterMore);

}
NSArray * allValues = [myExpenses allValues];
for (int i = 0; i < [allValues count]; i++) 
{
    Expense * myExpense = [allValues objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", [myExpense name]);
    NSLog(@"%f", [myExpense amount]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [myExpense dayOfMonthDue]);
}
```

The real power is that now, you can reference a value *by name*. For example:

```
Expense * anExpense = [myExpenses objectForKey:@"Expense Name"];
```

Hopefully this helps.

EDIT: Also, I notice you are not calling `-release` or `-autorelease` on your instances. You're either using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) or if you're still using MRR (Manual Retain-Release), you should be autoreleasing your Expenses. If you are using ARC, don't mind this, but if not - You will have memory leaks. Or you can explicitly call release (See: [Use autorelease before adding objects to a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147785/use-autorelease-before-adding-objects-to-a-collection))

Comment: First yes I am using ARC. And secondly thank you this really helps me out. Doing it the way I was doing it I could figure out the way too find a specific expense but it would have required some round about code, but this will allow me to just search for the name of the bill. Where as my way i would have to delve into the actually object to find the proper bill. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you could do for this is add the instances to a dictionary object (NSMutableDictionary) with which you can access each object with a key (NSString). This is a way to do this. Here is a reference to see more on diccionaries:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Dictionary_Objects

**UPDATE**: To answer the comment, I mean add the instances. The dictionary object is an array which uses a key to access the object instead of a number. The thing is, you can't dinamically create instances. It would be imposible to access as the compiler would not know wether those variables exist and would not compile. This is why it isn't allowed. What you can do is use a dictionary object. It is easier to access because if the user inputs  the expense name, it will be found more automaticaly thanks to the fact that the input would be a string.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Add *what* to a dictionary object, and *why*?